# Lightning combobox drop drown show on top of all elements

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I'm using a lightning-combobox and I have it inside a div section with slds-scrollable.

```
<template>
<div class="slds-box slds-scrollable">
<lightning-combobox
        name="progress"
        label="Status"
        value={value}
        placeholder="Select Progress"
        options={options}
        onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-combobox>

<p>Selected value is: {value}</p>
</div>
```

What's happening is when I click a drop down they go inside scrollable div context and I'm trying to display on top of scrollable div any solution please I tried z-index: huge number and didn't work.

[Click here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qkhftwYsn/1/edit) to see in playground.

Screenshots : Left is with scrollable and right is without scrollable

[image: Left is with scrollable and right is without scrollable]

I need a scroll bar but combobox menu should show on top of all elements.

Comment: why do you even want scrollable on combobox?

Comment: Hi @Salesforce-sas thanks for reply actually its in a custom table and the whole table is inside a div which have slds-scrollable. Just to drill down to problem I have written question like that, please note if I remove scrollable it works but I need that property too

Comment: Scrollable scopes the DOM in it. There is no work-around for this

Comment: Even style="overflow: auto" does the same,  I read about z-index which works but not in Salesforce I tried a lot.

Comment: Even z-index does not help when you add scrollbars. Z-index is for giving priority but scrollable just scopes the DOM inside it, so nothing we can do about it

Comment: @salesforce-sas found a way we can use style="position:absolute" but need to be careful with the position as it might cause to overlap. [Please check here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qkhftwYsn/1/edit)

Comment: @salesforce-sas yes but coz absolute position picklist values are being showed na on top? I mean I'm not css expert though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way we can use style="position:absolute" but need to be careful with the position as it might cause to overlap. [Please check here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qkhftwYsn/23/edit)

Comment: you are positioning it w.r.t window and thats why u r feeling its working. Check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qkhftwYsn/25/edit). When you position it w.r.t its immediate parent, it will start failing again. This is not workable solution.

Comment: @salesforce-sas  yes agreed. Just workaround,  in case you find something please do let know.